# Loop through values or registry key.. _winreg Python

Tags: python, windows, registry, enumeration, winreg

How would I loop through **all** the *values* of a Windows Registry Key using the Python module _winreg. I have code that will do what I want, but it is for the subkeys of the specified registry key.

---

**Here Is The Code:**

```
from _winreg import *
t = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r"PATH TO KEY", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

try:
    i = 0
    while True:
        subkey = EnumValue(t, i)
        print subkey
        i += 1
except WindowsError:
    # WindowsError: [Errno 259] No more data is available    
    pass
```

---

Oh, figured it out. But, if anyone knows of another way to do it, I'll still accept that answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shouldn't EnumValue be of help here

```
# list all values for a key
try:
    count = 0
    while 1:
        name, value, type = _winreg.EnumValue(t, count)
        print repr(name),
        count = count + 1
except WindowsError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 10):

I prefer to *avoid* the error instead of diving right into it ...

Use [_winreg.QueryInfoKey](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.QueryInfoKey) to get the number of values:

```
import _winreg
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'PATH\TO\KEY', 0, _winreg.KEY_READ)

for i in xrange(0, _winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[1]):
    print _winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
```

To get the number of Keys, same method, different index (second half of original question):

```
for i in xrange(0, _winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[0]):
    print _winreg.EnumKey(key, i)
```

*Note:* use `import` instead of `from ... import` to make it explicit where functions and variables are coming from.  Makes it easier to follow code later in life.

Comment: the `-1` in xrange leaves out the last key. I think it should simply be `for i in xrange(_winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[0]):`

Answer (score 2):

for python 3

```
import winreg
hKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "Local Settings\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Shell\\MuiCache")


try:
    count = 0
    while 1:
        name, value, type = winreg.EnumValue(hKey, count)
        print (name),
        count = count + 1
except WindowsError as err:
    print(err)
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

For iterating through keys and values of registry, you would need `EnumKey()` and `EnumValue()` method from `_winreg` module. Note that these two methods, take index as an argument, and will provide you the key (or value) only for the given index. Therefore, in order to get all the keys (or values) you need to increment the index by one and continue until `WindowsError` has not encountered.

[This post](https://pabitrap.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/accessing-windows-registry-using-pythons-winreg-module/) might help you for a detailed understanding on the same. The Github link for the code can be found in the post.

Answer (score 0):

(Python3) Using generators and recursivity as i don't like counters...

```
 def get_keys(self, path, i=0):
    try:
        yield winreg.EnumValue(winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path), i)
        yield from get_keys(path, i+1)
    except WindowsError as err:
        pass


for name, value, type in r.get_keys(r"Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache"):
    print(f"{name} => {value} ({type})"
```