# _winreg.EnumKey(key, i) does not workng?

Tags: python-2.7, winreg

Hy,
I trying to reconstruate a script. And in python 3 I used _winreg and the script was working, but I need it in python 2 and now  I get this erorr:

```
File "discoverNetworks.py", line 14, in printNets
guid = _winreg.EnumKey(key, i)
WindowsError: [Error 259] No more data is available
```

But of course in that folder is a lot of files.

This is the code:

```
import _winreg
def val2addr(val):
    addr = ''
    for ch in val:
        addr += '%02x '% ord(ch)
    addr = addr.strip(' ').replace(' ', ':')[0:17]
    return addr
def printNets():
    net = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\NetworkList\\Signatures\\Unmanaged"
    key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,net)
    print '\n[*] Networks You have Joined.'
    for i in range(100):
        try:
            guid = _winreg.EnumKey(key, i)
            netKey = _winreg.OpenKey(key, str(guid))
            (n, addr, t) = _winreg.EnumValue(netKey, 5)
            (n, name, t) = EnumValue(netKey, 4)
            macAddr = val2addr(addr)
            netName = str(name)
            print '[+] ' + netName + ' ' + macAddr
            _winreg.CloseKey(guid)
        except WindowsError:
            break
def main():
    printNets()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that it works in Python 3 but not in 2?

Comment: Yes. That's it! Any idea why?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17563506/868044

Comment: You either need to use exception handling to deal with this error or use the answer I just posted to avoid it

Comment: see my answer, I explain why it is different in 3.

Comment: Also, if you found my answer helpful, don't forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it solves your problem. If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

`EnumKey()` is designed to be called repeatedly until a `WindowsError` is thrown. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.EnumKey):

> winreg.**EnumKey**(*key, index*)
>
> . . .
>
> The function retrieves the name of one subkey each time it is called. It is typically called repeatedly until a `WindowsError` exception is raised, indicating, no more values are available.

However, the reason you did not receive a `WindowsError` when you ran it in Python 3 is because [the library changed in Python 3.3 to throw an `OSError` instead.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/winreg.html?highlight=_winreg#exception-changed)

In fact, `EnvironmentError`, `IOError`, `WindowsError`, `VMSError`, `socket.error`, `select.error` and `mmap.error` have been merged into `OSError` in 3.3 ([source](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#OSError)).

You can handle the error via exception handling (`except WindowsError`) or avoid it altogether by determining the number of values ahead of time with [`QueryInfoKey`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.QueryInfoKey) as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17563506/).