# How to get a list of installed windows fonts using python?

Tags: python, operating-system, os.path, listdir

How do I get a list of all the font names that are on my computer's system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a matter of listing the files in `Windows\fonts`:

```
import os

print(os.listdir(r'C:\Windows\fonts'))
```

The output is a list that starts with something that looks like this:

```
['arial.ttf', 'arialbd.ttf', 'arialbi.ttf', 'cambria.ttc', 'cambriab.ttf'
```

Comment: `os.listdir(os.path.join(os.environ['WINDIR'],'fonts'))` for generic use

Answer (score 6):

You could also use **tkinter** which would be better than list the font in `C:\Windows\Fonts`, because windows can also store fonts in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`

For example using the following code from [List available font families in `tkinter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614027/list-available-font-families-in-tkinter):

```
from tkinter import Tk, font
root = Tk()
print(font.families())
```

The output is a tuple that starts with something that looks like this:

```
('Arial', 'Arial Baltic', 'Arial CE', 'Cambria', 'Cambria Math'
```

If you prefer to get the font filename, you can use
[FindSystemFontsFilename](https://pypi.org/project/FindSystemFontsFilename/).

Example from the [doc](https://github.com/moi15moi/FindSystemFontsFilename/tree/main#how-to-use-it):

```py
from find_system_fonts_filename import AndroidLibraryNotFound, get_system_fonts_filename, FontConfigNotFound, OSNotSupported

try:
    fonts_filename = get_system_fonts_filename()
except (AndroidLibraryNotFound, FontConfigNotFound, OSNotSupported):
    # Deal with the exception
    # OSNotSupported can only happen in Windows, macOS and Android
    #   - Windows Vista SP2 and more are supported
    #   - macOS 10.6 and more are supported
    #   - Android SDK/API 29 and more are supported
    # FontConfigNotFound can only happen on Linux when Fontconfig could't be found.
    # AndroidLibraryNotFound can only happen on Android when the android library could't be found.
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

The Windows registry apparently keeps track of fonts:

```
import winreg

reg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)

key = winreg.OpenKey(reg, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts',
    0, winreg.KEY_READ)

for i in range(0, winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[1]):
    print(winreg.EnumValue(key, i))
```

The outputs starts with something that looks like this:

```
('Arial (TrueType)', 'arial.ttf', 1)
('Arial Bold (TrueType)', 'arialbd.ttf', 1)
('Arial Bold Italic (TrueType)', 'arialbi.ttf', 1)
('Cambria & Cambria Math (TrueType)', 'cambria.ttc', 1)
('Cambria Bold (TrueType)', 'cambriab.ttf', 1)
```

If you want simpler output like:

```
Arial (TrueType)
```

Use `print(winreg.EnumValue(key, i)[0])` instead of `print(winreg.EnumValue(key, i))` in the last line.

This was combined from Mujeeb Ishaque's respons as well as [Python code to read registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227107/python-code-to-read-registry) and [Loop through values or registry key.. _winreg Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974038/loop-through-values-or-registry-key-winreg-python)

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is going to list all the fonts path from the `/Windows/fonts dir`. However, some people might also want to get `the font title, its variations i.e., thin, bold, and font file name etc?` Here's the code for that.

```
import sys, subprocess

_proc = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', 'Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts"'], stdout=sys.stdout)
_proc.communicate()
```

Now, for the people who want font paths. Here's the way using `pathlib`.

```
import pathlib

fonts_path = pathlib.PurePath(pathlib.Path.home().drive, os.sep, 'Windows', 'Fonts')
total_fonts = list(pathlib.Path(fonts_path).glob('*.fon'))
if not total_fonts:
    print("Fonts not available. Check path?")
    sys.exit()
return total_fonts
```

Comment: The first code returns font names but also a strange vertical line of text while the second code doesn't work with Python 3, however many thanks for hinting towards the registry!