# How to find out available system fonts in Pycairo?

Tags: python, windows, fonts, pycairo

I'm writing SVG text in Pycairo and want to set the font like so:

```
context.select_font_face ("Adventure", Cairo.FontSlant.NORMAL, Cairo.FontWeight.BOLD);
```

(example from [Valadoc](https://valadoc.org/cairo/Cairo.Context.set_font_size.html))

but I want to know which font names I can use / are available without having to try and guess. I'm hoping I can generate a list with Python, ideally with Pycairo. I'm on Windows with Python 3.7.9 at the moment. I [can't find anything in the documentation](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=fonts&check_keywords=yes&area=default#).

There are good solutions at [How to get a list of installed windows fonts using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64070050/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-windows-fonts-using-python) but rather than getting surprised at some point, I'd like to find out which methods give me all the fonts Pycairo sees, including potential additional folders (like `%UserProfile%\.fonts\` for Inkscape) and excluding any paths it might not see.